# Laravel 5.1 basic authentication (register) does not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm very new to Laravel and PHP 5.4, coming from CI. Please forgive this stupid question about very basic authentication.

I am beginning by implementing login/registration (authentication), following [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication).

My migration is in place:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password', 60);
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->rememberToken();
    ...
});
```

Here's my **`config\auth.php`**:

```
'driver' => 'eloquent',
'model' => App\User::class,
'table' => 'users',
'password' => [
    'email' => 'emails.password',
    'table' => 'password_resets',
    'expire' => 60,
],
```

**`app\User.php`**:

```
protected $table = 'users';
protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password'];
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
```

**`app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php`**:

```
protected function validator(array $data) {
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data) {
   return User::create([
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}

public function getLogin() {
    return view('admin/login');
}

public function getRegister() {
    return view('admin/register');
}
```

**`app\Http\routes.php`**:

```
Route::get('admin/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('admin/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('admin/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('admin/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

My views are displaying properly:

```
resources/views/admin/login.blade.php
resources/views/admin/register.blade.php
```

with forms:

```
<form action="/admin/login" method="POST">
<form action="/admin/register" method="POST">
```

This is as far as I get. The Register form, when submitted, just redirects to itself, no errors. No entries are created in the `users` database table.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I don't think I need to add a `postRegister()` because it's already defined in the `RegistersUsers` trait used by `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` used by `AuthController`.

Also, not sure if this helps but I have 2 virtual hosts pointing to the same project directory.

Comment: Have you checked application logs ?  you can check the application logs in `storage/logs/laravel.log`, make sure you have set error_reporting(E_ALL), also check server logs

Comment: Should probably add your `postRegister()` method considering thats the method your posting to.. or are you using the defaults?

Also, check the network tab of your browsers developer tools, should tell you the response you got from the post request, which should hint at why you were redirected.

Comment: @GaneshGhalame I cleared the laravel.log and resubmitted the form. Nothing in the logs.

Comment: @Jeemusu I checked the Network tab, it seems the form is submitted using `GET` instead of `POST`, even though the `<form action="/admin/register" method="POST">`. Any idea why this is so?

Comment: @Jeemusu I just found that it actually does a `POST`, but status is `302 Found`. Then it makes the `GET`

Comment: @obay Sounds as though it's posting fine. Something is forcing it to redirect back, most likely it's the validation rules. Try removing your validation rules, or leaving them empty and then submitting the form. What does your form look like, I assume you have `email`, `password`, and `password_confirmation` named inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be definitively a validation error.

Put this code in your register view and try again:

```
<!--  Error handle -->
        @if($errors->any())
        <div class="row collapse">
            <ul class="alert-box warning radius">
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li> {{ $error }} </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `postRegister` to your AuthController:

```php
public function postRegister(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);

    return $this->create($request->input());
}
```

Also note that the `validator` function isn't really required. In 5.1, a `Controller` object has the `validate` method, which will return failures automatically.

Oh, and you should probably add `postLogin`, too. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: But `postRegister()` is already defined in the trait `RegistersUsers` which is `use`d by the trait `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers`, which I `use` in `AuthController.php`

Answer (score 0):

With a basic installation, a validation rule is running when registering. With no further error messages, it's a little confusing.

It's the password validation rule in `AuthController.php`, that wants a password length of minimum 6 characters:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}
```

So just make sure you enter 6 or more characters :)